# Receiving a daily reward

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm doing a daily reward system on my site.

Users can pick up the reward only once a day. The next reward can be picked up the next day, also, only once.

When a user visits the site to pick up a daily reward, I put a timestamp in the database (*e.g.* "2023-09-15 15:36") when the user picked it up. The number of consecutive rewards collected is totaled. Likewise, each time a reward is collected, I put in the database which consecutive day the user does it.

I wrote a function `checkRewardStatus(date)` for this purpose. It should return:

- `"you can claim your reward now"` if it is the next day (after the last time the reward was taken).
- `"time's up, you can't collect your reward."` in case the user hasn't collected the reward for the whole next day after the last collected reward.
- `"wait until tomorrow to pick up your reward."` in case the user picked up the reward today and wants to pick it up again today (this is not allowed).

**I'm not convinced that my function is 100% correct.** I would like to hear comments on my code: what are the drawbacks, what can be improved, modified. I will be glad to any answers, thanks!

````javascript
function checkRewardStatus(date) {
  let claimDate = new Date(date);

  const now = new Date();
  
  const nextDayStart = new Date(claimDate);
  nextDayStart.setDate(claimDate.getDate() + 1);
  nextDayStart.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  const nextDayEnd = new Date(claimDate);
  nextDayEnd.setDate(claimDate.getDate() + 1);
  nextDayEnd.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
  
  const claimDayStart = new Date(claimDate)
  claimDayStart.setDate(claimDate.getDate());
  claimDayStart.setHours(
    claimDate.getHours(), claimDate.getMinutes(), claimDate.getSeconds(), claimDate.getMilliseconds()
  );
  
  const claimDayEnd = new Date(claimDate);
  claimDayEnd.setDate(claimDate.getDate());
  claimDayEnd.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)
  
  if (now >= nextDayStart && now <= nextDayEnd) {
    return "you can claim your reward now"
  } else if (now > nextDayEnd) {
    return "time's up, you can't collect your reward."
  } else if (now >= claimDayStart && now <= claimDayEnd) {
    return "wait until tomorrow to pick up your reward."
  }
}

```
````

Comment: I think you need to clarify a couple things: a) when you say "day" does that mean the "after 24h"? For lots of people a day could be the calendar day, so Monday night at 11:50 PM and 20 minutes after on Tuesday at 00:10 AM would be two separate days. This also means you need to answer whether this is based on the timezone of the user or the server. Additionally, you need to clarify in your question that you are looking to reward users *only if they show up on consecutive days*, otherwise the "times up" message would not be unique, as that same user would be able to claim their next reward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simplify by dropping unnecessary computations

You only need the first line in this snippet, the rest of the lines set the same values the object already had:

> ```
>   const claimDayStart = new Date(claimDate);
>   claimDayStart.setDate(claimDate.getDate());
>   claimDayStart.setHours(
>     claimDate.getHours(), claimDate.getMinutes(), claimDate.getSeconds(), claimDate.getMilliseconds()
>   );
> ```

#### Simplify by using half-open intervals

To check the end of an interval with `<=`, the code computes the last millisecond of days using `.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)`. By adopting half-open intervals, the end can be checked with `<` and a simpler `.setDate(start.getDate() + 1)`.

#### Simplify using a function to compute key day boundaries

Computing "next day end" is a recurring operation in the code.
It makes sense to create a function for it.
By adopting the previous suggestion,
you can use one function to replace 3 manually computed dates.

#### Simplify using fewer variables

When multiple variables store the same value,
it can become difficult to keep track.

If you rename the function parameter to `claimDate`,
then you can eliminate `date`.

#### Order terms in conditions to have increasing value

Instead of:

> ```
> if (now >= nextDayStart && now <= nextDayEnd) {
> ```

Consider the equivalent condition, with the terms reordered by increasing value:

> ```
> if (nextDayStart <= now && now <= nextDayEnd) {
> ```

This way it's easier to see that `now` is in between values.

#### Use terminating semi-colons consistently

Most lines end with a `;` but not all.
Use terminating `;` consistently everywhere or nowhere.

#### Alternative implementation

Putting the above suggestions together:

```
function nextDate(date) {
  const copy = new Date(date);
  copy.setDate(copy.getDate() + 1);
  copy.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  return copy;
}

function checkRewardStatus(claimDate) {
  const now = new Date();

  const nextDayStart = nextDate(claimDate);
  const nextDayEnd = nextDate(nextDayStart);

  const claimDayStart = new Date(claimDate);
  const claimDayEnd = nextDate(claimDayStart);

  if (nextDayStart <= now && now < nextDayEnd) {
    return "you can claim your reward now";
  } else if (nextDayEnd <= now) {
    return "time's up, you can't collect your reward.";
  } else if (claimDayStart <= now && now < claimDayEnd) {
    return "wait until tomorrow to pick up your reward.";
  }
}
```

Comment: `nextDay` is a more correct name/descriptor than `nextDate`.

Comment: Think about creating properties for `start` and `end`  =>  `nextDay.Start` and `nextDay.End`.  These nicely express "parts of the Day";  is very OO; and at the same time significantly reducing the number of loose variables lying about. `checkRewardStatus` length will be cut in half

Answer (score 0):

## what is a day?

The business requirement is that we can collect a reward just once in a "day".
Defining the notion of a Day hasn't quite been nailed down yet.
Your webserver connects to the internet,
a planetary audience with diverse times of local sunrise.

> I'm not convinced that my function is 100% correct.

Your users aren't convinced, either.
That is, it's a bit difficult to describe
to users living in the capitals of Canada, U.K., and India
what a "same day" pair of requests would be.
Also, your diagnostic messages do not indicate
how long one should wait till a retried request might succeed.

```
function checkRewardStatus(date) {
  let claimDate = new Date(date);
```

The claim date describes an historic event that definitely happened,
a successful claim. Ideally the database would store it as a UTC timestamp.
What's missing from the function signature is the user's local zone offset.
That should be a user attribute persisted in the DB, which can only be changed
a couple of times a week so we don't see 24 updates on Monday to make 24 claims.

---

## half-open interval

```
  if (now >= nextDayStart && now <= nextDayEnd) {
    ...
  } else if (now > nextDayEnd) {
    ...
  } else if (now >= claimDayStart && now <= claimDayEnd) {
```

You track times to the second and even millisecond level,
which probably isn't necessary for this problem.
When reviewing those `if`s, imagine we had minute or even just hour granularity.

We should see greater consistency of `>` versus `>=`.
Define a day to be the [half-open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints) `[start, end)` interval,
rather than the closed `[start, end]` interval used by the code.
Now the conjuncts compose nicely,
and there's no ambiguity about whether a certain midnight instant
falls in Monday or in Tuesday.

---

## client vs server context

In the OP it is unclear where the code runs.
Hopefully it runs on your server,
where you know that the zone offset
and the NTP-synchronized clock are set
to something sensible.

You wouldn't want to delegate security decisions
to a client-controlled environment where things
like reported wallclock time could be arbitrarily manipulated.